# How to activate Shifting props in React Navigation Library?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have `navigation tab` with 3 options and I want to activate the `shifting props` utilized in `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` taken from the `react navigation` library but I can't find where I need to put the `shifting props="true"` for activate the option